# MS word get value from table active cell

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

Is there a way in MS word get the current value from table active cell

Comment: May try `Selection.Cells` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.cells)   and then use `Range.Text`

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
MsgBox Split(Selection.Cells(1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
```